# Animations in Williamchart

Tags: android, charts

I just found the library Williamchart https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/769.

There are many different `Easings` to animate the graph... I think... https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/wiki/(7)-Animation

It has really cool animations to bring the graphs in front. But: how? Has anybody a usefull example how to bring a line chart as cool as on the website I linked to the front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `Animation` class which is imported from `com.db.chart.view.animation.Animation` and use `setEasing()` function.

```
BarChartView chart=(BarChartView)findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    BarSet dataSet=new BarSet();
    dataSet.addBar(new Bar("first", 5));  //or whatever data you have
    dataSet.addBar(new Bar("second",7));
    dataSet.addBar(new Bar("third", 4));
    dataSet.addBar(new Bar("forth", 3));
    chart.addData(dataSet);

    Animation anim = new Animation(3000);
    anim.setEasing(new LinearEase());     //choose your animation here
    chart.show(anim);
```

You can use `LinearEase`,`BounceEase`,`ElasticEase`,`CircEase`,`CubicEase` etc in the place of `new LinearEase()`.

Comment: But now i can't use this animation. https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/blob/master/williamchart/src/main/java/com/db/chart/animation/Animation.java

Comment: @Shiv: years passed man. Many updates are there. most of the libraries got obsolete. Don't know about this.